# How to delegate to services by class type?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have different class types, and depending on some conditions, I want to delegate to the appropriate `service` that can handle those class types.

Example:
I have several classes as follows.

```
class Student;
class Prof;
...
```

For each class there is a service, implementing:

```
interface IPersonService {
    void run();
}
```

And I have a `mode` that is found by some conditions:

```
enum PersonType {
    STUDENT, PROF;
}
```

When I delegate:

```
@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@Autowired
private ProfService profService;

//@param mode assume known
public void delegate(PersonType mode) {

    //assume there are several of those switch statements in my business code
    switch (mode) {
        case STUDENT: studentService.run(); break;
        case PROF: profService.run(); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

**Problem**: When introducing additional classes, I have to both modify the `PersonType` and add an additional enum (which is no problem), but I also have to extend any `switch` statement and add calls to additional delegation services. Also I have to explicit autowire those services to the switch delegator.

**Question**: how could I optimize this code, to just implementing new Services for any additional class, and not having to touch any of the switch statements?

Comment: you can keep a mapping in enum itself to associate PersonType with the Service and in delegate just get the service based on PersonType & call it.

Comment: But I cannot inject the services into the enum, can I?

Comment: The root of the problem is that service logic is separated from the data it services. Separating data and logic is called [Procedural Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming). In [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), service logic is combined with the data it services, so there is no need to 'delegate'.

Comment: @jaco0646 to how would you rewrite or improve the example given?

Comment: I wouldn't be interested in rewriting the code. I want to point out that the current answers are procedural solutions to a procedural problem, whereas _java design patterns_ are always object oriented in my experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a method to `IPersonService` so that the implementation of the method can tell the program what type of persons it handles:

```
interface IPersonService {
    PersonType supportedPersonType();
    void run();
}
```

In the service that does the delegation, inject a `List<IPersonService>`, which Spring will fill with all the implementations of `IPersonService` that it can find. Then implement the `delegate` method to look through the list to find the first `IPersonService` that can handle the specific type.

```
@Autowired
private List<IPersonService> personServices;

public void delegate(PersonType mode) {
    for (IPersonService personService : personServices) {
        if (personService.supportedPersonType().equals(mode)) {
            personService.run();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can add new implementations of `IPersonService` without having to change the service that does the delegation.

To avoid having to go through the loop each time `delegate` is called, you could build a `Map` beforehand so that the right `IPersonService` can be looked up quickly:

```
class DelegatingService {
    @Autowired
    private List<IPersonService> personServices;

    private Map<PersonType, IPersonService> personServiceMap;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        personServiceMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (IPersonService personService : personServices) {
            personServiceMap.put(personService.supportedPersonType(), personService);
        }
    }

    public void delegate(PersonType mode) {
        personServiceMap.get(mode).run();
    }
}
```

(Error handling omitted for simplicity).

Comment: That's a very nice and probably the correct solution to my problem!

Answer (score 1):

In my application, we solved similar problem, by putting services into a map. Consider `Map<PersonType,IPersonService> serviceMap` defined as bean and injected into your class.
Then delegate method simple do

```
public void delegate(PersonType mode) {
    IPersonService service = serviceMap.get(mode);
    if (service!=null){
        service.run();
    }else{
        //do something if service is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the service bean name (or class type) in the enum, and fetch the beans from the application context using getBean by name (or by class type respectively).

Also, all the services will need to implement a interface which has the run method.

```
interface ModeService {
    void run();
    }

    enum PersonType {
        STUDENT("studentService"), PROF("profService");
        private String serviceBean;
        public PersonType(String serviceBean) {
              this.serviceBean = serviceBean);
        }
        public String getServiceBean() {
               return serviceBean;
        }
    }
```

in delegate then the following can be used. `((ModeService)applicationContext.getBean(mode.getServiceBean()).run()`

This way only the enum needs to be updated with the service type that is to be used, and no change to delegate method is required.